# When is a memory allocated to a variable

Tags: memory

These three sentences are a bit confusing for me.

> 1.Memory is allocated during initialization of a variable.
>
> 2.Memory is allocated during declaration of a variable.
>
> 3.Memory is allocated during definition of a variable.

Any explanation is welcome! Thanks a lot

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: #Chuck...It's C ..Sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a compiled language, I'd say none of these.

A global variable is assigned a memory offset at compile-time and the latter is made absolute at link-time. A local variable is assigned an offset in a stack frame.

At load-time (when the program is loaded from disk for execution), the memory space for all global variables is mapped to the memory space of the process and the variable is implicitly allocated some space, statically; it the variable has been declared with an initial value, it is set on that moment. Stack space is also reserved.

At run-time, when you enter a function, a stack frame is pushed on the stack, containing space for the local variables.

In no case are variables "allocated memory" individually and neither initialization nor declaration nor definition have any allocation effect at run-time.

Take

```
int g= 1;

void main()
{
  int l= 2;
}
```

The first variable definition, `g`, causes four bytes of global space to be mapped (in addition to all other global variables) and initialized to `1` by the loader when the program is loaded. The second variable definition, `l`, causes four bytes to be mapped (in addition to all local varibles) on the stack frame of the call to main and be automatically set to `2` when the function is entered.

Uninitialized variables have an undefined value until you assign them some. This is because the run-time environment just takes the memory space as it is, with its previous, unpredictable content, to spare the cost of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It laregly depends on which programming language you use, and where is this variable declared.

For instance in Objective Pascal if you declare global application variavle, the memory manager will memory manager will reserve memory for this variable right at the application start.

If you have local variable declared (variable is declared within a method) in Objective Pascal memory will get reserved when code will step into this method.

When memory gets reserved for some variable the variable doesent necesarily gets initialized. It laregly depends on variable type, where it was declared and what memory manager are you using.